# AngularJS resource results are undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is possibly just the way I am accessing the resource object but I have the service below:

```
angular.module('appointeddPortalApp')
.factory('Salon', function ($resource) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    // Public API here
    return $resource('http://api.appointeddcore.dev/organisation/:id', {id: '@id'}, { 
        update: { method: 'PUT' }, 
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: false} 
    });
});
```

I'm using the `query` method like this:

```
var data = Salon.query($scope.options);
console.log(data);
```

From the console.log() :

```
Resource {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove:
function, $delete: function…} 
offices: Array[20]
total: 33
__proto__: Resource
```

My problem is trying to access `total` or `offices` I get undefined

```
console.log(data.total); // undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Salon.query() returns immediately with an empty object and updates the variable data if the data is present, try this:

```
var data = Salon.query(function(callbackdata){
   //function is called on success
   console.log(callbackdata);
   console.log(callbackdata.total);
});
```